# Swift, xcode v 8.2

Tags: swift, macos-sierra, xcode8.2

So I am working on a project, the other developer has the most recent updates for mac OS sierra and the newest xcode updates. The build works on his mac, but when I run it on my "New" Mac Book. With a new install of xcode, I get build and compiler errors as such.

```
class QueueSubscribeOn<Element>: Cancelable, ObservableType, ObserverType, DelayedObservableType {
typealias E = <#type#>                         Error: Editor placeholder in source file
```

I shouldnt have to change the code at all I wouldnt think, i imagine it has something to do with the build. But I havent been able to figure it out! Thanks

Comment: Looks like there is an editor placeholder in the code. Try to remove it or add the correct type.

Comment: How is Xcode 8.2 the "newest Xcode updates"? Version 9.0 is the newest.